# Outlook HTML - Signature editing without autospace

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

For a Windows server (16) environment I push different HTML e-mail signatures (Outlook) to all users.

**The issue: After adding the signature, Outlook sets an unwanted autospace after each paragraph (enter). I want to change the HTML, so that hitting enter does not result in extra whitespace (so similar to shift+enter).**

[Signature example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/819jy.png)

The signature works as it is supposed to. I have sent an e-mail to myself to take a look at the HTML body created by Outlook. As is known from previous posts, this is entirely different from the HTML which I've added.

Looking at the HTML created by Outlook, after manually changing the autospace to 0, Outlook has created many paragraphes, all containing the following statement: style='text-autospace:none'

Since hitting enter results in new paragraphes which do not contain this style-tag, this does not resolve my issue. Using this same style tag in an overarching div, span or table does not solve my issue. I've tried working with paddings and margins, but this has no effect on the paragraph autospace.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and update your question. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you want to do, **show your code** so we can see what have you have tried so far.